# Calculate Duration by Columns

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with five columns (visit date, doctor, patient id, start time),
I want to add a new column "Duration", this column will calculate the duration of each visit.
I tried to rank the times per visit date and doctor, but I could not subtract the time between the rows.

```
| visit date | Doctor   |  P id  |   Time   |
|------------+----------+--------+----------|
| 2018-08-02 | Doctor 1 |   10   | 05:10:00 |
|------------+----------+--------+----------|
| 2018-08-01 | Doctor 2 |   12   | 12:20:00 |
|------------+----------+--------+----------|
| 2018-08-03 | Doctor 1 |   07   | 06:30:00 |
|------------+----------+--------+----------|
| 2018-08-01 | Doctor 1 |   55   | 05:40:00 |
|------------+----------+--------+----------|
| 2018-08-01 | Doctor 2 |   60   | 02:50:00 |
|------------+----------+--------+----------|
| 2018-08-02 | Doctor 1 |   17   | 10:10:00 |
|------------+----------+--------+----------|
| 2018-08-02 | Doctor 1 |   20   | 13:00:00 |
|------------+----------+--------+----------|
| 2018-08-01 | Doctor 2 |   19   | 20:10:00 |
|------------+----------+--------+----------|
| 2018-08-03 | Doctor 1 |   60   | 02:20:00 |
|------------+----------+--------+----------|
| 2018-08-03 | Doctor 1 |   11   | 13:30:00 |
```

The rank column I created:

```
Rank = 
RANKX(
    FILTER(
        FILTER(
            'test 2',
            'test 2'[Doctor]=EARLIER('test 2'[Doctor])
        ),
        'test 2'[Visit Date]=EARLIER('test 2'[Visit Date])
    ),
    'test 2'[Time],
    ,
    ASC,
    Dense
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a new calculated column "Visit End":

```
Visit End = 
LOOKUPVALUE(
    'test 2'[time],
    'test 2'[Visit Date],
    'test 2'[Visit Date],
    'test 2'[Doctor],
    'test 2'[Doctor],
    'test 2'[Rank],
    'test 2'[Rank]+1
)
```

After adding this new column it is easy to calculate the duration, the new "Duration" column will be like this:

```
Duration = DATEDIFF('test 2'[time],'test 2'[Visit End],MINUTE)
```